# vertical expand content boxes

Tags: html, css, positioning

I always have a problem trying to figure out the best way to make expandable content boxes. I used to use tables and cut the box into sections (top, bottom, left and right - then each corner in a table cell too, with an expandable middle cell for the content) This worked flawlessy on all browsers but its generally frowned upon.

Today i have an image which i need need to only expand vertically. however it has a drop shadow and the top 200 pixels or so has a gradient. Heres a link to the image im working with.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/brandinfobox.png/

The content needs to flow and the div needs to expand vertically as the content grows. Ive looked at a few approaches but ive either not been successful or they have just not worked in some browsers. The main problem is the drop and shadow and top gradient. Those stop me from using a base background then absolute positioning some divs inside as the background ruins the drop shadow when i absolute position the outer edges.

Any advice? Sure its fairly simple if you know your way around css

Comment: Can that element have a min-height? If yes than the answer is simple!

Comment: Yes it can have a min-height. In fact it would probably be better to have a min-height than not too as it needs to match the height of a sidebar, or be greater than that sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a linear-gradient in CSS3.

For the surrounding rounded box with drop shadow, whether I go for 100% CSS3 or two background images and an extra div would depend of the requirements of my client.

Comment: i thought about CSS3 but its not an option. Its a social orientated site, which means looks are very important. I cant have browsers (IE) not applying the shadow. and because of its intended audience, i expect a high majority of the traffic will be IE users

Comment: didn't know IE supported alternative methods for this. I'll have to google and look up the filter stuff. As long as i can have the gradient never expand past xxx pixels i can just scrap the image altogether. Thankyou !

Answer (score 3):

May be you can do like this for this type of image & gradient

### http://jsfiddle.net/wh6r4/

**edit: added CSS code**

```
.content{
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/5hN1S.png) repeat-y top left;
    width:647px;
    min-height:300px;
    position:relative;
    margin:50px;
}
.y-repeat{
    position:absolute;
    left:2px;
    right:7px;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/bJmR4.png) repeat-x top left;
}
.top, .bottom{
    background: url(http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/3301/brandinfobox.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    height:20px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
.top{
  top:-20px;
}
.bottom{
  background-position:left bottom;
  bottom:-20px;
}
```

Comment: I was just thinking about doing something like this. It's the fallback plan if the browser specific gradient properties posted by roXon dont all allow setting the gradient to fade into a color at exactly the same Y-position no matter how high the div is

Answer (score 2):

If that box can have a min-height than here are some ex. how to do it:

```
<div id="box-top"> // CSS bg image = 600*8px with rounded corners 
<div id="box-middle"> // CSS bg image = 5*80px vertical tiny gradient line ; min-height!  
<div id="box-bottom"> // CSS bg image = 600*8px with rounded corners
```

**OR EVEN BETTER:**

You can make expand a gradient image  inside the middle DIV, by setting `position:absolute`, `width 100%` and `height:100%` !!

```
<div id="box-top"> // CSS bg image = 600*8px with rounded corners 

<div id="box-middle">
 <img class="box_mid_img" src="vertical_gradient_image.png"> // CSS: .box_mid_img width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute
</div>

<div id="box-bottom"> // CSS bg image = 600*8px with rounded corners
```

---

Another trick is to simply use a CSS3, you'll get support for IE gradients but not for shadows and corner (border) radius.

http://jsbin.com/uberub/2/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: Thanks, think i got enough info to get it done. Re: the fancy css for drop shadow and gradients in non-css3 browsers.... if you check out your jsbin in IE, the shadow doesnt play nicely with rounded corners. Typical IE :)

Answer (score -2):

I would split the image into three horizontal strips. One for the top, including the rounded corners, one for the bottom, including corners and shadow, and one very thin strip for the middle.

Then with markup like this:

```
<div style='background-image: url("middle.png"); width: 400px;'>
    <img src='top.png'>
    Expanding content in the middle
    ...
    Can be as big as you like
    <img src='bottom.png'>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought about this, however that would mean the content cannot get to the top and bottom of the box. I need the content to start ON the gradient at the top, not below it. Also setting a wrapper with the middle section would ruin the drop shadow unless i applied a solid matte to the shadow so that the middle background didnt show through. Thanks for the reply though